# creating an array from incremental calculations in small data set

Tags: r

For a particular small data set containing 7 items, I have created the following new array:

```
f.rhs <- c((-orig_qty + looped_data$TOTAL_EFFECT[1])/looped_data$MULTIPLE_ORDER_QTY[1],
             (-orig_qty + looped_data$TOTAL_EFFECT[1] + looped_data$TOTAL_EFFECT[2])/looped_data$MULTIPLE_ORDER_QTY[1],
             (-orig_qty + looped_data$TOTAL_EFFECT[1] + looped_data$TOTAL_EFFECT[2] + looped_data$TOTAL_EFFECT[3])/looped_data$MULTIPLE_ORDER_QTY[1],
             (-orig_qty + looped_data$TOTAL_EFFECT[1] + looped_data$TOTAL_EFFECT[2] + looped_data$TOTAL_EFFECT[3]+ looped_data$TOTAL_EFFECT[4])/looped_data$MULTIPLE_ORDER_QTY[1],
             (-orig_qty + looped_data$TOTAL_EFFECT[1] + looped_data$TOTAL_EFFECT[2] + looped_data$TOTAL_EFFECT[3]+ looped_data$TOTAL_EFFECT[4] + looped_data$TOTAL_EFFECT[5])/looped_data$MULTIPLE_ORDER_QTY[1],
             (-orig_qty + looped_data$TOTAL_EFFECT[1] + looped_data$TOTAL_EFFECT[2] + looped_data$TOTAL_EFFECT[3]+ looped_data$TOTAL_EFFECT[4] + looped_data$TOTAL_EFFECT[5] +looped_data$TOTAL_EFFECT[6])/looped_data$MULTIPLE_ORDER_QTY[1],
             (-orig_qty + looped_data$TOTAL_EFFECT[1] + looped_data$TOTAL_EFFECT[2] + looped_data$TOTAL_EFFECT[3]+ looped_data$TOTAL_EFFECT[4] + looped_data$TOTAL_EFFECT[5] +looped_data$TOTAL_EFFECT[6] + looped_data$TOTAL_EFFECT[7])/looped_data$MULTIPLE_ORDER_QTY[1])
```

As you can see, this code is very very ugly. Essentially what's happening is at each new value, we are taking the previous values and adding some new stuff to it from the next line of data(incremental calculations essentially).

How would I go about doing this same process and making this row for a dataset containing an arbitrary amount of observations?

Answer (score 2):

Using `cumsum()` would help you. Something like this maybe:

```
f.rhs = (-orig_qty + cumsum(looped_data$TOTAL_EFFECT)) / looped_data$MULTIPLE_ORDER_QTY[1]
```